# Load Balancing ActimeMQ Artemis in JBoss EAP 7.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, load-balancing, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

We are developing an application using Spring Boot and Apache Camel that is reading a message from ActiveMQ Artemis, doing some transformation, and sending it to ActiveMQ Artemis. Our application is deployed as war file in on-premise JBoss EAP 7.2.0. Both the source and target applications are remote to our application and they are also deployed on JBoss EAP 7.2.0. The remote queues to which Camel is connecting are ActiveMQ Artemis which were created in JBoss and connecting using http-remoting protocol. These setup was working when there were only one node of each of the applications.

Now we are making the source and target applications 3 nodes each (i.e. they will be deployed in multiple JBoss servers). For accessing the front-end of the source and target applications we are configuring and accessing them through a load balancer.

Can we configure the load balancer to access the source and target brokers from the Camel layer? There will be 3 source and 3 target brokers. Or is clustering the brokers the only option in this case?

We are thinking of load balancing between the queues and not clustering. Suppose we have three queues `q1`, `q2`, and `q3` with corresponding brokers `b1`, `b2`, and `b3`. I will configure the load balancer url in the Camel layer like `http-remoting://<load-balancer-url>:<port>` (much like we do while load balancing HTTP API requests). Any message coming in will hit the load balancer, and the load balancer will decide which queue to route the message to.

Comment: Yes correct Justin

Comment: We are thinking of load balancing between the queues and not clustering, I will let you know the load balancer product, meanwhile wanted to check on feasibility of the approach as I was unable to find anything on internet

Comment: Not exactly like this, suppose we have three queues q1, q2 and q3 with corresponding brokers b1, b2 and b3. J will configure the load balancer url in camel layer like http-remoting://<load-balancer-url>:,<port> (much we do while load balancing API requests). Any message coming in will hit the load balancer and it will decide which queue to route the message to

Comment: Ok thanks, will look at it and get back. Yes I want to balance load at message level just like API load balancer.

Comment: If I hit an URL (HTTP request) from browser or application which is a load balancer url, the request hits the load balancer and the load balancing policy (e.g. round robin) determines in which backend service the request will go to. This thing I was referring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS connections are *stateful*. When a client creates a connection there is no indication of the queues to which it will send messages. The load-balancer will have to direct that client's connection to either `b1`, `b2`, or `b3` and it will have no way to determine where it should go. A load-balancer working with messaging will almost certainly only be able to balance *connections*, not messages. It sounds like you want load-balancing at the message level instead. Perhaps you should look into something like [Qpid Dispatch Router](https://qpid.apache.org/components/dispatch-router/index.html).

Messaging doesn't use HTTP so using an HTTP load balancer like you do with your HTTP API(s) won't work. It's easy for a load-balancer to inspect HTTP headers and route requests, especially since HTTP is stateless. However, messaging connections are stateful and the protocols are typically quite a bit more complex than HTTP. I don't know of any load-balancers that will work the way you are wanting for messaging.

Answer (score 0):

You need your client not to use the topology, you can do this by using "setUseTopologyForLoadBalancing" on your AMQConnectionFactory. If you get the connection factory from EAP I think this is configurable on the connection factory since EAP 7.3.

Comment: Can you please guide me hot to do this? Does this need to be defined in standalone-full.xml where we are defining the connection factories? Suppose my target contains three JBoss nodes and correspondingly three target queues, do we need to define this in each of the three JBoss server's standalone-full.xml?

Comment: Yes in EAP 7.3 you can define that in the (pooled-)connection-factory elements https://docs.wildfly.org/20/wildscribe/subsystem/messaging-activemq/server/connection-factory/index.html#attr-use-topology-for-load-balancing. But this might not be what you need re-reading your  edited question as this is in case you can't access the nodes directly

Comment: Thanks, I will go through this if this helps